# Attempting to sort graphQL order by position with DatoCMS adn Gatsby JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, content-management-system, gatsby

I am using this Gatsby JS plugin to explore the DatoCMS GraphQL API https://github.com/datocms/gatsby-source-datocms In the dato docs it says you can order by position in the cms https://www.datocms.com/docs/content-delivery-api/ordering/

I basically want to preserve the order in the cms, not have it order based on date.

In the dato API Explorer I can order posts by position like so.

```
query MyQuery {
  allProjects(orderBy: position_ASC) {
    slug
  }
}
```

However in Gatsby the same query alludes me I have tried something like this below but it gives me this `error Expected type SortOrderEnum, found position_ASC`

```
query MyQuery {
  allDatoCmsProject(sort: {order: position_ASC}) {
    edges {
      node {
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the gatsby plugin the syntax is slightly different the DatoCMS graphQL explorer This is how the plugin expects me to do my ordering if I wanted to order it by a particular field. However I can't find any field that would allow me to order by position of the elements in Dato cms

```
{
  allDatoCmsBlogPost(sort: { fields: [publicationDate], order: DESC }, limit: 5) {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        excerpt
        publicationDate(formatString: "MM-DD-YYYY")
        author {
          name
          avatar {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your Model has "visualisation mode" of table, a property called `position` get's added.

[image: Records collection visualization mode "Tabular view"]

We can use this `position` to sort the records like this:

```
allDatoCmsProject(sort: { fields: [position], order: ASC }){
...
}
```

Comment: Hey, this does not seem to work anymore I think?

Answer (score 1):

From the [gatsby-source-datocms README](https://github.com/datocms/gatsby-source-datocms):

> IMPORTANT: If you use this plugin, you will not be able to write queries as described in the DatoCMS Content Delivery API documentation. Content will be exposed using Gatsby's schema-generation. If you want to directly use our GraphQL API in Gatsby, consider using the gatsby-source-graphql plugin instead.

Comment: Damn I just saw that so I guess I'll have to rewrite a bunch of my queries then?

Comment: I found a way thankfully, but thank you for your response, it is a important thing to note with choosing your source plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in 2024 trying to do this what worked for me was:

Selecting model, clicking edit model, then scrolling down and setting "How should we order this collection of records?" to "Records can be sorted by editors via drag & drop" (+ restart local build).

Then querying as so:

```
query {
    allDatoCmsTimesAvailable(
    sort: {position:ASC}
  ) {
      nodes {
      time
      position
    }
    }
    
}
```

On the content tab if you click the settings gear "position" can also be added as shown.
[image]